# What is the opposite of precision called?

Tags: model-evaluation

I know that $$precision = {\text { true positives } \over \text { predicted positives}}$$

but what about ${\text { true negative} \over \text { predicted negative}}$? what is it called?

Thanks

Comment: Opposite is a pretty vague term in the title.

Comment: @qwr English is not my native language. That was the term that came up in my mind. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be called the negative predicted value.

[See wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_predictive_values)

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity) is most comprehensive.

Comment: Such a sad name but it is what it is